# Can a vfx graph be affected by a wind zone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-effects

I made a fire using vfx graph and I put it under a pan model for cooking effect. The thing is that the fire rises vertically and goes through the pan like if nothing is there. When I used a particle system I prevented particles from going through objects using a wind zone and external forces option activated.

My question is: can I do the same using vfx graph? if not, any ideas how to emulate the effect I'm looking for? Thank you.